# YO - unexpected token error

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Running yo gives invalid token error. Currently using Node, NPM versions as given below.
node -v
v4.5.0
npm -v
2.15.9

```
$ yo
node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js   
let lookup = path.join(...parts.slice(0, i + 1), 'node_modules');
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Comment: Hey Uday, Can you provide more details to your questions such as, what version of NPM you are running and any error that you are running into. Also, what steps you did to get that invalid token error?

Comment: Node, NPM versions as given below. node -v v4.5.0 npm -v 2.15.9

Comment: node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js   
let lookup = path.join(...parts.slice(0, i + 1), 'node_modules');
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>

Answer (score 6):

things worked after moving to node -v v8.11.1 and npm -v 5.6.0

Comment: This means latest version should be OK...  So, I applied node:13.13.0 as of today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your node major version matches the node version you installed yeoman using.