# Yo Code "Error code Unexpected token '('"

Tags: npm, vscode-extensions, yo

For some context:

- I am running the latest version of Pop OS
- I am running npm version 8.5.1
- I am running nodejs version 12.22.9
- I installed yo@4.3.1 and generator-code@1.7.8

Whenever I run `yo code` in Terminal, I receive the error:

```
Error code

Unexpected token '('
```

I also attempted to use `yo code` on older versions: yo@4.0.0 and generator-code@1.6.0.

I found an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-generator-code/issues/419) opened on vscode-generator-code Github 2 months ago. This user had the same problem I experienced.

I also found a 5 year old post about a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441693/yo-unexpected-token-error).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?
I have been running into the same error. I am on Ubuntu

Comment: The problem was with generator-code and not yo. I installed yo@4.3.1 and downgraded to generator-code@1.3.0. The Github Issue I linked in my post is still open and as far as I know, there is no current fix for the latest version of generator-code.